# Vue 3 cdn example with vuex 4, but how do I access the store inside main.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vuex, vuex4

**My app structure:**

```
> public 
>   scripts
>     - cdn
>       - vue.js
>       - vuex.js
>     main.js
>     store.js
>     index.html
```

Inside the head tag I have:

```
<script src="./scripts/cdn/vue.js"></script>
<script src="./scripts/cdn/vuex.js"></script>
<script src="./scripts/main.js" type="module"></script>
```

And in the body I have-

```
<div id="app"> <div v-for="item in items" >{{item.text}}</div> </div>
```

***store.js***

```
console.log('test in store.js', store.state)
const store = new Vuex.createStore({
  state: {
    items: [{
      text: 'ahhh STORE 1'
    }, {
      text: 'ahhh STORE 2'
    }],
  },
  mutations: {

  },
  actions: {
    test({
      state
    }) {
      console.log(state.items)
    }
  },
  modules: {

  }
})
```

***main.js***

```
import * as store from "./store.js";
const {
  onMounted,
  onUpdated,
  onUnmounted,
  ref,
  reactive,
  getCurrentInstance
} = Vue; //here define only what you need
//Define Vue app
const App = {
  state: store,
  // store, //using either store or state: store does not work

  data() {
    return {};
  },
  methods: {},
  setup(props, context) {
    onMounted(() => {
      console.info("App mounted!");
      console.log('mounted state', store.state)
    });
    onUpdated(() => {
      console.info("App updated!");
    });
    onUnmounted(() => {
      console.info("App unmounted!");
    });
  }
};
// Create new Vue app
const app = Vue.createApp(App);
app.use(store)
app.mount("#app");
```

So when the app runs, in the console it shows

```
test in store.js Proxy { <target>: {…}, <handler>: {…} }
```

But in `onMounted` it returns `store.state` as `undefined`.
It can work by using `createStore` inside `main.js` but I would like to keep this separated.

What am I missing and how do I make the store accessible in the main?

Comment: Just a PS: why are you loading CDN files locally? Either use the CDN directly or import an NPM package. Right now, you have no benefits at all.

Comment: This is just a local app that won't be connected to the internet, but I appreciate you reading all the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also faced the similar problems while integrating Vuex 4 with Vue CDN
Look at my folder structure

```
>Components
-HelloWorld.js
>store
-index.js
app.js
index.html
```

in the index.html file include the vuex 4 CDN link then in for the index.js file inside store folder include the store like this

```
const  store = new Vuex.Store ({
state: {
  //states
},
mutations: {
  //mutations
},
actions: {
  //actions
},
getters: {
  //getters
},
```

});

export default store`
Inside the app.js root folder include the store as

```
import store from './Store/index.js'
app.use(store);
```

Access the store from the component level without importing like the following

```
this.$store.//store function
```

Answer (score 3):

`app.use(store)` -
you have already added the store to the vue instance.

Then you can access this storage from any component, for example using:

```
   import { mapState} from 'vuex';
   ...
   computed: {
    ...mapState({
      items: state => state.items
    }),
  },
```

or in `setup`:

```
import { useStore } from 'vuex';
...
setup(){    
  const store = useStore();
  const state = store.state; // <-- state from vuex
}
```

Your working example:

```js
const store = new Vuex.createStore({
  state: {
    items: [{
      text: 'ahhh STORE 1'
    }, {
      text: 'ahhh STORE 2'
    }],
  },
  mutations: {

  },
  actions: {
    test({
      state
    }) {
      console.log(state.items)
    }
  },
  modules: {

  }
})

const {
  onMounted,
  onUpdated,
  onUnmounted,
  ref,
  reactive,
} = Vue; //here define only what you need



//Define Vue app
const App = {
  data() {
    return {};
  },
  methods: {},
  computed: {
    ...Vuex.mapState({
      items: state => state.items
    }),
  },
  setup(props, context) {
    const store = Vuex.useStore()
    onMounted(() => {
      console.info("App mounted!");
      console.log('mounted state', store.state)
    });
    onUpdated(() => {
      console.info("App updated!");
    });
    onUnmounted(() => {
      console.info("App unmounted!");
    });
  }
};
// Create new Vue app
const app = Vue.createApp(App);
app.use(store)
app.mount("#app");
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex@4.0.0/dist/vuex.global.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-for="item in items">{{item.text}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello, thank you so much for replying! Strangely I get this error when using Vuex.mapState TypeError: this.$store is undefined and with ...mapState I get mapState is not defined but it's read Vuex.createStore in store.main

Comment: use `import { mapState } from 'vuex';`

Comment: Sorry, it returns Uncaught SyntaxError: ambiguous indirect export: mapState. I've tried import * as Vuex from "./cdn/vuex.js"; and then changed mapstate to Vuex.mapState but this still returns Vuex.mapState is not a function

Comment: for the detection probability will be `import { mapState } from './scripts/cdn/vuex.js'`

Comment: When I tried with ./scripts/cdn.vuex.js it returns Loading module from “http://localhost:3000/scripts/scripts/cdn/vuex.js” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”) but then it returns as ambiguous without scripts in the path. In my store.js file it uses new Vuex.createStore which is imported into main so shouldn't it be usable from there or am I missing something else? Thank you so much for the help

Comment: The idea is that you need to get the helpers from the vuex file as you get the `createStore` function. If you have it local, then get it from a local file by analogy, as you get for `createStore`. example: `import { createStore, mapState, useStore } from 'path_to_vuex'` - replacing with the path to your vuex file. 
Be careful with the paths, because the wrong path will get an error

Comment: is it causing an issue when my createStore is inside store.js? I can log Vuex inside setup in main.js and it will return: Object { version: "4.1.0", Store: Store(options), storeKey: "store", createStore: createStore(options), useStore: useStore(key), mapState: Vuex(namespace, map), mapMutations: Vuex(namespace, map), mapGetters: Vuex(namespace, map), mapActions: Vuex(namespace, map), createNamespacedHelpers: createNamespacedHelpers(namespace), … } The store was already created in store.js but it's empty even though it should have items in

Comment: could you build your minimal example on codesandbox?

Comment: Hello, sorry I couldn't get it to work on codepen! I will update eventually but thank you for all the help